# how to replace static elements initialization for Command pattern?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, enums, static-initialization

I want to replace `if else` statements:

```
    if (userSalutation.equalsIgnoreCase("mr")) {
        screenPage.selectMr();
    } else {
        screenPage.selectMs();
    }
```

`selectMr()` performs just click on this buttons.

With ***Command pattern*** implementation.
Using ***enums*** implementation for this aim.

I have to use if for web page elements (buttons):

[image]

***Code snippet***:

```
public class ScanScreenPageStep1 extends PageObject {
    public ScanScreenPageStep1() {
        PageFactory.initElements(new EasyWebFieldDecorator(getDriver()), this);
    }
    @FindBy(id = "salutation")
    protected Button mr;

    @FindBy(id = "salutation2")
    protected Button ms;
```

Here is ***enum looking***:

```
public enum PersonSalutations {
        MR("mr") {
            @Override
            public Button getButton() {
                return mr;
            }
        },    
        MS("ms") {
            @Override
            public Button getButton() {
                return ms;
            }
        };
        private String salutation;

        PersonSalutations(String salutation) {
            this.salutation = salutation;
        }

        public static final Map<String, Button> stringToButton = new HashMap<>();            
        static {
            for (PersonSalutations salut : values()) {
                stringToButton.put(salut.toString(), salut.getButton());
            }
        }

        public String getSalutation() {
            return salutation;
        }

        public abstract Button getButton();

        public static Button fromString(String stringSalutation) {
            return stringToButton.get(stringSalutation);
        }    

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return salutation.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

For adding buttons element to `stringToButton` I have to make my button element static:

```
@FindBy(id = "salutation")
protected static Button mr;

@FindBy(id = "salutation2")
protected static Button ms;
```

***How to avoid making elements static at this case?***

Or some other circumstances at this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `enum` defines the conceptual button, while `protected Button mr` defines an *instance* of the button. Except for singleton pattern, that's like asking a `Class` for an instance of the class. Your code has more than one instance of `Button`, so singleton doesn't apply here.

You should move `getButton` to `ScanScreenPageStep1` as follows:

```
public Button getButton(PersonSalutations s) {
    if (s == PersonSalutations.MR)
        return this.mr;
    if (s == PersonSalutations.MS)
        return this.ms;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid: " + s);
}
```

As an alternative, add `ScanScreenPageStep1` as a parameter to `getButton`, so the enum known *which* "step 1" instance to get the button of.